# hdfs: Failed to place enough replicas: expected size is 2 but only 0 storage types can be selected

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

It was working fine, not sure what changed and suddenly got this error.

Hdfs is running on a docker cluster (1 rm + 2 nodes).
works fine inside the containers, so there is no problem with data nodes.
Thrown when copy file from host machine to hdfs, with code or hdfs commands.

The error stack is from hadoop-root-namenode-master.log.

```
2017-10-26 09:18:05,102 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.BlockStoragePolicy: Failed to place enough replicas: expected size is 2 but only 0 storage types can be selected (replication=2, selected=[], unavailable=[DISK], removed=[DISK, DISK], policy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]})
2017-10-26 09:18:05,102 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Failed to place enough replicas, still in need of 2 to reach 2 (unavailableStorages=[DISK], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}, newBlock=true) All required storage types are unavailable:  unavailableStorages=[DISK], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}
2017-10-26 09:18:05,103 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 7 on 9000, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 192.168.1.6:52435 Call#7 Retry#0
java.io.IOException: File /spark/apps/spark-app.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 2 datanode(s) running and 2 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
```

Source code is:

```
    System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "root");
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path("src/main/resources/core-site.xml"));      
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path(jars/spark-app.jar"), new Path("/spark/apps/spark-app.jar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a lot of time surfing, but after I changed the log4j level to **DEBUG**, I quickly located the problem. Log shows the client is connecting "172.20.0.3" which is the ip of datanode and not accessible from the host. Then add a route to 172.20/16 (`route add -p ...`), and it works fine now.

Comment: Hey, can you please help me with this? I am facing the same issue. How did you change log4j level to debug?

Answer (score -1):

When trying to copy a file to my cluster I received a similar message. All I had to do was to stop the firewall in my datanodes, using:

service firewalld stop